# How Do I do nested ifs? discord.js

Tags: node.js

Hi so I am coding a discord bot and I want to have nested ifs

```
let msg1 = 0;
let msg2 = 0;
client.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.content === ".tstart"){
    message.channel.send("Hello so you want to start a tournament? reply with yes or no")
  }
   if(message.content === "yes"){
    message.channel.send("Perfect, tell me the number of the members participating")
    if(message.content){
    msg2 = (message.content)
    console.log(msg2)
  }
  }
```

I want that after .tsart I want yes to be under it only, right now if I right yes it sends the text, I want it so that only when I have typed .tstart only then only writing yes would give its following text also how do I store the author's (user's) text? I am trying to store it with message.content but it justs give me what I wrote first time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well documented piece of question in the wild cause this is the most common scenario for a interactive discord command. (for example making a giveaway).

You need to use a message collector to do this here is the doc: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors

From the doc which you can repurpose for your code:

```
const quiz = require('./quiz.json');
const item = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];
const filter = response => {
    return item.answers.some(answer => answer.toLowerCase() === response.content.toLowerCase());
};

message.channel.send(item.question).then(() => {
    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
            message.channel.send(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer!`);
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            message.channel.send('Looks like nobody got the answer this time.');
        });
});
```